# Magento 2 bind ko scope to a non-html/virtual element

Tags: magento2, customer, scope, data-bind, accessibility

I want to bind customer scope to a non-html element as I do not want html to be loaded if customer is not logged in.
In the OOTB magento inside vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
li tag is loaded even if customer is not logged in. Visually the li is hidden in this case but the accessibility screen reader reads it.

I want to bind a scope to a non-html element so that I can write a condition something like below.

```
<!-- ko scope: customer -->
        <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
        <li class="greet welcome">
            <span class="logged-in"
                  data-bind="text: new String('<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1')) ?>').replace('%1', customer().fullname)">
            </span>
        </li>    
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
```

But scope is not bound.

```
knockout.js:3381 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return customer().firstname }"
Message: customer is not defined.
```

Any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scope you should use a **String**. Try:

```
<!-- ko scope: 'customer' -->
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much @JanuszJanczy :)

Comment: Thanks for this, do you happen to have a link to the knockout/magento documentation for this? I have been googling for a while and I can't find anything but this question and answer